# Porting a MS Access 2003 Application to VB6 [Printing Reports] -> MS PowerPack 3

Tags: ms-access, printing, vb6

I have several forms in MS Access 2003 that are beeing used as Reports to print out. Now I've tried recreating them in some VB6 Forms. So far so good. The problem is, im lacking an option to print them or to make a way to print them using the standart printer. I've found on google that the `MS Powerpack 3` Component provides some printer functionality. I've installed it from the MS Homepage, but even though I restarted Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, it does not appear to be selectable as Component.

So I have several questions:

- Why can't my Visual Studio 2006 find the `MS Powerpack 3 Component`?
- Are there any better alternatives for form printing
- (Maybe even, is there a component providing functionality equal to the MS Access 2003 reports)
- (Additionally maybe, maybe I can somehow reuse parts or all of the reports for my application in vb6)

Comment: Visual Studio 2006 (= .net) or VB6 (old  Visual Basic now obsolete)! Which are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0

Comment: The code has to run on everything from Windows 95 to Windows 7

Comment: Those "Power" Packs are VB.Net compatibility crutches and not related to or usable in VB6.

Comment: If somebody was using MS Access UserForms as "reports" I can only shake my head.  Are you sure these aren't Access Reports?  There are far better ways to create reports than by printing an image of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169), it appears that the "Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0" consists of several components / libraries.

Maybe you are simply looking for the wrong component name?

> The **Printer Compatibility Library** allows projects that used the Printer and Printers Collection in Visual Basic 6.0 to be upgraded without having to re-write your printing logic. By simply adding a reference to the library, declaring a Printer and making a few minor syntax changes, your project will be able to print using the Printers collection and Printer object as it did in Visual Basic 6.0. This version adds a new Write method to the Printer object which allows you to print text without a forced carriage return similar to the semicolon syntax used by Print method in Visual Basic 6.0.
>
> The **PrintForm component** is designed to bring back the ability to easily print a Windows Form. With this the new PrintForm component you can once again layout the Windows Form exactly as you want it and allow your users to print the form as a quick report.